# Is there an easy way to compose an object from other objects?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, object-composition

Is there an easy way to compose an object based on other objects?
i am thinking the solution lies using DI container & Interfaces
eg.

```
public IObjectA : IObjectB, IObjectC {...}

public ObjectA CreateObjectA()
{
 ObjectB b = new ObjectB();
 ObjectC c = new ObjectC();
 return container.GetExportedValues<IObjectA>(b,c);
}
```

The whole idea is not to write any mapping code to create an object.

Comment: THe question is a bit unclear.  Just to confirm, can you specify which language you are talking about?  Typically Objects are instantiations of a class so you can't really make an object based on other objects.  If your intent was regarding classes, you can derive a new class based on an existing class and add functionality to it or you can create a new class that contains members that are objects of a different type.

Comment: The language is c#, what i mean is something like Instantiate, Cloning the objects, then return a new object. i think i can write a generic method to do it but wondering if it was already done. Thanks

Comment: Did you try Automapper?

Comment: Thanks, i will use ValueInjecter. answered this but it was deleted